# Swing auto repaints JPanel after button clicked

Tags: java, swing

I'm having this weird issue with Swing.
I am drawing few points and lines between them, directly on JPanel.
I'm just calling:

```
g.drawLine(pointAX, pointAY, pointBX, pointBY);
```

Where g is `Graphics` object taken from `panel.getGraphics()`

And this works alright, gives me nice output.
But then I'm trying to move it and I use `ActionListener` on my button, which does:

```
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
    drawPanel();
    moveVector(moveX, moveY);

    drawPoints();
    drawConnections(connections);
```

The other methods:
`drawPanel` just draws some lines, so it's easier to see:

```
private void drawPanel(){
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    zeroX = panel.getWidth() / 2;
    zeroY = panel.getHeight() / 2;

    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    for(int i = zeroX + 10; i < panel.getWidth(); i += 10){
        g.drawLine(i, 0, i, panel.getHeight());
    }

    for(int i = zeroX + 10; i > 0; i -= 10){
        g.drawLine(i, 0, i, panel.getHeight());
    }

    for(int j = zeroY - 10; j < panel.getHeight(); j += 10){
        g.drawLine(0, j, panel.getWidth(), j);
    }

    for(int j = zeroY - 10; j > 0; j -= 10){
        g.drawLine(0, j, panel.getWidth(), j);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(zeroX, 0, zeroX, panel.getHeight());
    g.drawLine(0, zeroY, panel.getWidth(), zeroY);

    panel.paintComponents(g);
}
```

`drawPoints` looks like this

```
private void drawPoints() {
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++){
        int x = Integer.parseInt(points.get(i)[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(points.get(i)[2]);
        drawPoint(x, y);
    }
}

private void drawPoint(int x, int y) {
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
        g.drawLine(zeroX + x + i, zeroY + y - 1, zeroX + x + i, zeroY + y);
    }

    panel.paintComponents(g);
}

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(zeroX, 0, zeroX, panel.getHeight());
    g.drawLine(0, zeroY, panel.getWidth(), zeroY);

    panel.paintComponents(g);
}
```

and `drawConnections`:

```
private void drawConnections(ArrayList<String[]> lines) {
    for (String[] arr : lines) {
        String x = arr[1];
        String y = arr[2];

        drawConnection(x, y);
    }
}

private void drawConnection(String pointA, String pointB) {
    int pointAX = 0, pointAY = 0, pointBX = 0, pointBY = 0;
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

    for (String[] arr : points) {
        if (arr[0].equals(pointA)) {
            pointAX = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            pointAY = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
        } else if (arr[0].equals(pointB)) {
            pointBX = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            pointBY = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
        }
    }

    g.drawLine(zeroX + pointAX, zeroY + pointAY, zeroX + pointBX, zeroY + pointBY);
    panel.paintComponents(g);
}
```

What I don't understand here is that everything looks OK. I did debug and it looks ok and at the end of listener call, when everything is painted (although it paints over the old one instead of clearing it)  it suddenly clears everything and nothing is visible at all.

Comment: could you show your complete code? (May be at any other site like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/))

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pLrKd7AB
Here is the code
Worth to mention that I'm using IntelliJ and it uses some kind of creator to help make GUI. It hides some of the implementation

Comment: `getGraphics` is not how painting is done, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details...

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement all the drawing in `paintComponent(Graphics)` in your `JPanel` class (or methods that are called from it). Calling `getGraphics` on the panel instance and using the Graphics object is not always guaranteed to work. It's also strange that you call `panel.repaint()` and immediately afterwards try to do additional drawing using the graphics object from the panel, that additional drawing should just be done in `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Using `paintComponent(Graphics)` will ensure your painting is done at the right time, and that the panel's graphics will be cleared (if you call the super method at least).

Answer (score 0):

`panel.repaint` does not immediately repaint the panel, but it tells Swing that this panel should be repainted in the near future (see API docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int). So your custom painting will be cleared once the panel repaints itself.

Create a custom component by inheriting from JPanel and overwriting the method `paintComponent` with your custom painting code. Then, whenever the panel needs to be repainted, your code is called, and not only the user pressed a button.